# Bug in android? #000 shows up as white on ICS devices

Tags: android, background

Ok, this is realy weird:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //doStuff();
    }
```

This is my onCreate, there is NO other code being executed!

somelayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >     
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/prevnext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000001">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/prev"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="prev"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/leftbtn" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="next"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/rightbtn" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/group"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="text"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="18dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

The background of root ('bg.png') is a dark background which is shown correctly,
the background of prevnext acts really weird:

background = #000 -- wrong: shows up white

background = #000000 -- wrong: shows up white

background = #F00 -- correct

background = #0F0 -- correct

background = #000001 -- correct

Comment: hey @Ferdau are you changing the background at all dynamically?  Maybe it is related to this defect http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22917&q=background%20xml%20color&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars  ?

Comment: Thanks alot, it's weird and doesn't make any sense... I change the background in other activities, but not at al in this one, so yes probably has something to do with that issue!

Comment: you should defiantly add your case to the bug report, because it didn't seem like they had a case where the background was set in xml and then changed.  That could insure that the future fix includes your usecase.